# What is this type of command: command-name > &! file-name

Tags: command-line

Somewhere I encountered a Terminal command that has the following format:

```
command-name > &! file-name
```

What is supposed to do?

Comment: this is very vague what is the exact command?

Answer (score 5):

The only shell that I know of in which `> &!` is valid is `(t)csh`. From `man tcsh`:

> ```
>    > name
>    >! name
>    >& name
>    >&! name
>            The  file  name  is used as standard output.  If the file does
>            not exist then it is created; if the file exists, it is  trun‐
>            cated, its previous contents being lost.
>
>            If the shell variable noclobber is set, then the file must not
>            exist or be a character special  file  (e.g.,  a  terminal  or
>            `/dev/null') or an error results.  This helps prevent acciden‐
>            tal destruction of files.  In this case the `!' forms  can  be
>            used  to suppress this check.  If notempty is given in noclob‐
>            ber, `>' is  allowed  on  empty  files;  if  ask  is  set,  an
>            interacive confirmation is presented, rather than an error.
>
>            The  forms  involving `&' route the diagnostic output into the
>            specified file as  well  as  the  standard  output.   name  is
>            expanded in the same way as `<' input filenames are.
> ```

Ex. if `file` exists but `nofile` doesn't, then

```
$ csh -c 'set noclobber; ls -l file nofile > & outfile'
$ cat outfile
ls: cannot access 'nofile': No such file or directory
-rw-r--r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 70 Nov 22 15:10 file
```

Then

```
$ csh -c 'set noclobber; ls -l file nofile > & outfile'
outfile: File exists.
```

But adding `!`

```
$ csh -c 'set noclobber; ls -l file nofile > &! outfile'
```

succeeds. So the `!` has a somewhat similar meaning to that in `vi`.

Comment: It seems to me that apersand (`&`) has different meanings in different contexts. For instance, this article (https://bashitout.com/2013/05/18/Ampersands-on-the-command-line.html) explains that apersand at the end of a command causes to run it in the backround.